# Is there any rule of thumb on how much or how less I should put a UI content on a screen?

Tags: navigation, cognitive-load

I get a dilemma over whether I should spread my content over several pages to reduce user cognitive load, or put as much information as possible in a screen to lessen the navigation depth.

For example, if I am to display a list of jobs a user must do at a certain time, there are choices of:

1. Put only task name and countdown for each row. User have to tap the row to see the detail. But the user interface is very clean.
2. Put the task name, location, and schedule for each row. Now the user *_may_* have enough information to do his task without tapping the detail, but for each row, it becomes considerably more complex now I can hear someone say "you may as well put everything there".
3. Put all data including the project title, and client name. Now the user can see everything on the row and does not need to tap to open detail (except if they need action buttons, which I too can provide using triple dot drop down menu for each row). But each row now is very tall and complex.

I understand that the situation may vary greatly with different requirements and clients, and no one rule fits all. But I just feel that no matter which level of detail and depth I use, sometimes all of them just feels wrong.

Btw, I'm at an early phase of composing some sort of solution for user's requirement to give him some minimum viable idea, so I don't have information at hand about real end user feedback given the proposed UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It depends on the content, its audience, and context.

E.g.
 - in Japan, information is often condensed.

- in a Car while moving, only information important to the driver should be shown and it should be glanceable.
- in a hospital, for the sake of sterilisation it may be wiser to provide a lot more information so as to avoid the need for paging.

A way forward for you may be to allow the user to decide (settings) and/or automate the users progression through settings based on their interaction and use of the application (e.g. after some time, advance the user to a more "power user" setting).

Comment: An evolving UI based on user's proficiency. Yea I didn't think about that. Alright thanks!